# If I move fast with mouse e.pageX doesn't recognize the path

Tags: jquery, mousemove

I've got this code:

```
$("#element").mousemove(function(e) {

   if(e.pageX == 255) {alert("here");}

});
```

When I move fast with the mouse it doesn't recognize the whole path it moves, it returns for example 260 and then 210 - not like I'd expect 260,259,258... Here comes the issue - I can't get catch exact moment when I passed the position, because it doesn't return this position. Is there any other way to get this position pixel after pixel? Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle? Hard to tell what your problem is...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nughett/v4gTV/

Comment: You can see that if you move your mouse too fast over the black element it will do nothing. But if you move slow over the element it will pop up the alert window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get the browser to notify you of every pixel.  The best you are going to do is every certain number of milliseconds (probably browser specific).

You can compensate for this by checking if you have crossed the position each time your function is called.  It is not perfect, but it's better:

http://jsfiddle.net/v4gTV/2/

```
var prev = null;

$("#element").mousemove(function(e) {

    var now = e.pageX;

    if((prev < 50 && now > 50) || (prev > 50 && now < 50) || now == 50) {alert("crossed");}

    prev = now;
});​
```

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me this way, but same comment goes here: I don't want it to pass the point. This evaluets when it passes the point.

Comment: If it's impossible how do they evaluate the position of this div: [link](http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/draggable-options.html) It hits the border and doesn't go over it even though my mouse move is pretty fast. I guess they are using totally different technique.

Comment: Because they check at each interval, if the mouse is outside the bounds and if so, don't move the box beyond the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of current and test if value is ">" or "<" your value then trigger your event once each time it passes your point

Comment: The problem is that I don't want it to pass the point. This is just an example of what I'm trying to achieve, but what I really do is that I'm moving a div with my drag and drop script and I want it to stop on certain border (wrapper div or some sort of thing) - if I pass the border and than I return the div back it looks weird, because it should stop right when it hits the border. I guess I'll have to use jquery UI anyway.